# How to know if nothing was printed on a foreach (blade template)

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 nested loops in my laravel view

```php
@foreach ($clubs as $club)
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
<h1>{{$club->nom}}</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h3>Grupos</h3>
        @foreach ($grupos as $grupo)
            @if ($grupo->club == $club->id)
                <p>
                    <strong>Nombre: </strong> {{$grupo->nom}} <br>
                    <strong>Tipo: </strong> Grupo de {{$grupo->tipo}} <br>
                    <strong>Horario disponible: </strong> {{$grupo->dia}}, {{$grupo->horario}} <br>
                </p>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endforeach
```

$grupos is an array with all groups from my group table, I iterate through the whole thing and print the info only if the foreign key club is equal to the current club that is iterating at the moment. If there's none, no information will be printed, but I would like to print a message that indicates that nothing was printed during that iteration, is there any way I could do it?

This is an example of my desired output

Club A with id 1 has 5 groups

Club B with id 2 has 0 groups

------ CLUB A -------

Group 1

Group 2

Group 3

Group 4

Group 5

------- CLUB B -------

This club has no groups

Comment: You should definitely be handing the view an array where only the elements you want printed exist, rather than doing the check inside of your loop. This simplifies your logic because now you can simply do `if (!$grupos) /* nothing to print */` before your loop begins.

Comment: you are definitely encouraged to up-vote the answer you've selected if you've found it helpful as this helps others with the same/similar question find the answer more easily and give credit to the person who provided the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need some relationships to achieve this. At this point, `$grupos` is the same for all the clubs. Here is how your minimum table structure should be:

> **clubs**

```
id (BIGINT 20)
name (VARCHAR 255)
```

> **groups**

```
id (BIGINT 20)
name (VARCHAR 255)
club_id (BIGINT 20)
```

Now you can set up your models:

> **Club.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Club extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'clubs';

    public function groups () {
        return $this->hasMany(Group::class);
    }
}
```

> **Group.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Group extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'groups';

    public function club () {
        return $this->belongsTo(Club::class);
    }
}
```

Now, in your controller where you load your view, you can get all your data and pass it through:

> **ClubController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Club;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ClubController extends Controller
{
    public function index (Request $request) {
        $clubs = Club::with('groups')->get();
        return view('clubs', ['clubs' => $clubs]);
    }
}
```

Now, display the clubs in your view:

> **clubs.blade.php**

```
@foreach($clubs as $club)
    <h1>Club: {{ $club->name }}</h1>
    @if($club->groups)
        <h2>Groups:</h2>
        <ul>
            @foreach($club->groups as $group)
                <li>{{ $group->name }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @else
        <h2>This club has no groups.</h2>
    @endif
    <br>
@endforeach
```

I hope this helps you and gives you a better understanding on how to use relationships in Laravel :)

Comment: I've edited your code with a slight performance enhancement and readability enhancement. You don't have to check `if (count($club->groups) > 0)` and especially inside of a loop since function calls can be expensive in PHP. According to [the PHP truth table](https://www.php.net/types.comparisons) all non-empty arrays are truthy and all empty arrays are falsey. So you can simply check `if ($club->groups)` instead :) Here's a working proof of concept to demonstrate https://3v4l.org/dFStX

Comment: Will groups being an empty array "[]" return true or false?

Comment: Edited the answer, added club_id to the groups table. It is required